# How to insert condition in Laravel One-to-one table relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a this method in a Laravel Controller that retrieves all records from the Contact table:

```
public function handle(Request $request) {

            $tasks = ContactTask::with([
                'contact:id,first_name,last_name,email,telephone',
                'user:id,first_name,last_name',
                'reference'
            ])->get();

        if ($request->queue) {
            $tasks = $tasks->where('queue', $request->queue);
        }
        if ($request->status) {
            $tasks = $tasks->where('status', $request->status);
        }
      

        return response()->json([
            'data'   => $tasks->paginate(50),
            'status' => HttpCodes::OK],
            HttpCodes::OK);
    }
```

I want that the relation "reference" would handle a One-to-One relation to another table in a Model, as  listed below:

```
public function reference() {           
            switch($this->reference_type){
                case 'request_id':
                    return $this->hasOne(Request::class, 'id', 'reference_id');
                case 'call_id':
                    return $this->hasOne(Call::class, 'id', 'reference_id');
                default:
                    throw new \Exception('Exception');
            }
        }
```

During the execution of this snippet, it throws the excpetion: seems that Laravel cannot find every single record of the parent table.

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: First of all, you need to provide error messages when asking questions. Second, it sounds like what you actually want to use is a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Comment: Also I'd suggest getting rid of `get()` in your controller method. Do the filtering and pagination at the database level rather than pulling every single database record at once.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a polyphomic relationship here

```
class Request extends Model
{
    public function reference()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Reference::class, 'referenceable');
    }
}

class Callextends Model
{
    public function reference()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Reference::class, 'referenceable');
    }
}

class Reference extends Model
{
    public function referencable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

for more details:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations